# Can't override class method with monkey patching in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, monkeypatching

So I am trying to **override the class method** `reflect_on_association` in `ActiveRecord::Reflection`. Here's the link to the original file: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb

The method was defined on line 106.

These are my attempts so far:

1.

```
ActiveRecord::Reflection::ClassMethods.module_eval do
  # A test method
  def say_hello
    puts 'hello'
  end

  # I want to override the original method with this one
  def reflect_on_association(association)
    puts 'overridden!'
    # < Implementation goes here >
  end
end
```

2.

```
module ActiveRecord::Reflection::ClassMethods
  # A test method
  def say_hello
    puts 'hello'
  end

  # I want to override the original method with this one
  def reflect_on_association(association)
    puts 'overridden!'
    # < Implementation goes here >
  end
end
```

The `say_hello` methods works for both cases (for example when I call `Person.say_hello`), but still no luck with `reflect_on_association`.

Anyone has any idea on how I can do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Where are you doing the overriding? Load order might be important. Try inside an Initializer.

Comment: yeah I'm already putting it inside `config/initializers`

Answer (score 0):

working in may case!

make sure you are passing parameter with reflect_on_association.

```
1.9.3-p551 :514 > Person.reflect_on_association(state)
overridden!
=> nil
```

Comment: Oh my. Are you doing it the first or second way?

Comment: @joeleba the Second way